# How to listen multiple event with @OnEvent decorator?

Tags: nestjs

I'm writing code for an event listener in Nestjs that uses the @OnEvent decorator. But when I add more events in square brackets, the program doesn't work.

If I add each event for each @OnEvent decorator the program works, but the code is verbose. I have tried with wildcard CONVERSATION_MODIFY = 'conversation.*' and success, but I want a solution to add as many events as I want. Sorry about my English

Code:

```
@OnEvent([CONVERSATION_UPDATE, CONVERSATION_DELETE, CONVERSATION_CREATE], {async: true,})
async handleOrderCreatedEvent(payload: ConversationChangeEvent) {
    await this.lessonService.getAssetById(payload);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```js
import { applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OnEvent } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';

const OnEvents = (events: string[]) =>
  applyDecorators(...events.map((e) => OnEvent(e)));
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use wild cards, documentation link : https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/events

```
@OnEvent('order.*')
handleOrderEvents(payload: OrderCreatedEvent | OrderRemovedEvent | OrderUpdatedEvent) {
  // handle and process an event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, you can use wildcards (*) to achieve this, but it is necessary to normalize the messages emited to a common prefix.
Which seems to be pretty simple in your case, something like
`@OnEvent('CONVERSATION_*')`

check the documentation link : https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/events

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible since `@OnEvent` only accepts single event unless you want develop your own `@OnEventS` decorator.

I suggest alternate approach, You can use a unified event name such as `CONVERSATION_EVENT` instead of `CONVERSATION_UPDATE`, `CONVERSATION_DELETE` and... etc and put a new property such as `eventType` to event's payload so you can emit single `CONVERSATION_EVENT` for any conversation change and use `eventType` property to detect if conversation is updated or deleted... .  With this approach you need to only listen to `CONVERSATION_EVENT`.